# Predicate for searching NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, nsarray, nspredicate, predicate

I need some help to figure out the correct `NSPredicate` syntax to correctly search my array that is like:

```
    CSVFinalData: (
    "Width:1,5 Diameter:12 Strength:0,25 Strength:900 Mode:L Spring:371M ",
    "Width:2,2 Diameter:6,5 Strength:0,45 Strength:1200 Mode:M Spring:485M ",
    "Width:3,5 Diameter:14,5 Strength:0,3 Strength:1600 Mode:M Spring:380M ",
    "Width:5 Diameter:7 Strength:0,25 Strength:850 Mode:L Spring:525M ",
    "Width:4,2 Diameter:10,2 Strength:0,4 Strength:1200 Mode:S Spring:1232S ",
    "Width:3 Diameter:6,8 Strength:0,15 Strength:800 Mode:S Spring:1439S ",
    "Width:1 Diameter:4,7 Strength:0,12 Strength:450 Mode:L Spring:129M ",
    "Width:7,3 Diameter:15,5 Strength:0,5 Strength:1400 Mode:M Spring:563M "
)
```

This is my `NSPredicate`:

```
NSPredicate *csvsearch =
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"'Width:' MATCHES %@", searchBar.text];
```

I also tried some other predicates but the result is empty on every time.
The only exception is when `searchBar.text` is 'Width:' it will show every object.

I am using Xcode 6.1 and iOS 8.1.

Thanks for your help!

@edit:

I played around a bit with @Larme solution. `CONTAINS` is too imprecise. When searching for a `Width` of 4,2 it will also find rows with `Diameter` 4,2. This should be theoretically correct:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self CONTAINS 'Width:4,2'"];
```

to make it dynamic I changed it to:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self CONTAINS '%@:%@'", csvHeaderName1, searchBar.text];
```

But once it is dynamic it won't work anymore but I don't get why :(

`csvHeaderName1` hast the content "Width" and `searchBar.text` "4,2"

Comment: This should do the trick: `@"self BEGINSWITH %@", @"Width:1,5"` You may want to use `CONTAINS` instead of `BEGINWITH` if you want to filter other parameters (like Diameter).

Comment: What is the exact scenario for your search? Can you provide an ideal input/output example?

Comment: @Larme Thanks. I will try it out.     
An example would be: 
Input: 4,2
Output:
"Width:4,2 Diameter:10,2 Strength:0,4 Strength:1200 Mode:S Spring:1232S "

Comment: You aren't representing your data using the best data structures which is why you are having such a difficult time.  That should not be an array of strings, rather an array of custom objects, each of which was created from parsing the string.  Your development experience will be complicated due to this.

Comment: Yes I know that. But this needs to help out for now as its importance is not that high.